# Wildfly connection pool exhausted on canceled HTTP requests

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, wildfly, connection-pooling

I have a Java EE application running on Wildfly 10 with RESTeasy and Hibernate. The application is pretty simple, it has entities, DAOs and resources:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    // ...

}

@Stateless
public class MyDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public List<MyEntity> list() {
        return this.em.createQuery("select e from MyEntity e", MyEntity.class).getResultList();
    }

}

@Path("/resource")
public class MyResource {

    @Inject
    private MyDAO dao;

    @GET
    public List<MyEntity> get() {
        return this.dao.list();
    }

}
```

So I do not use any JDBC connections directly, I delegate it all to JPA.

Problem is: no matter how many large my connection pool is, it eventually gets exhausted. Since datasource connections are handled in stateless beans, AFAIK connection opening/closing should be handled seamlessly.

Investigating on this connection leak, I've found out that I have many

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-25) UT005023: Exception handling request to /resource: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: RESTEASY003770: Response is committed, can't handle exception
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
```

exceptions, caused by canceled HTTP requests on the client side. Could these exceptions generate the connection leak? I hope not, since a client side action should not be able to exhaust the server connection pool.

Question is: may the problem be the canceled HTTP requests, how can I instruct Undertow/RESTeasy/Hibernate to handle that and exit cleanly? Where else could be the leak or how can I investigate to find out?

## Update 1

[REMOVED]

## Update 2

The last update (canceled HTTP requests) was misleading: further tests show how this happens in other cases, such as scheduled tasks (Java EE `@Schedule`) and event observers (Java EE `@Observe`).

The updated question is: when using JPA only to access the database, what could prevent a connection on being released?

Comment: If you just make the connection pool larger, you're giving more work to the database server. It can handle more connections, but at the same time each operation takes more time to finish due to the load.

Comment: Please, add the `MyDAO#list()` method.

Comment: @Kayaman thank you for the tip, I actually made the connection pool a lot larger since otherwise it gets exhausted pretty fast.

Comment: @v.ladynev done, it's a simple JPA query.

Comment: So have you done anything to find out how ineffective your queries are, whether your transactions are too long, or anything that would *actually* matter? Is your workload too big for your database, or is your code just very inefficient?

Comment: @Kayaman thank you, I have updated the answer with additional informations!

Comment: @Heruan A broken HTTP request won't result in a checked out connection in any well behaving (and correctly configured) pool. How many `MyEntity`s do you have in the database?

Comment: A few thousands, but very simple: in the actual scenario they are log entries which the end user can filter in the web application with subsequent requests (often canceling the previous ones, if not completed yet).

Comment: @Heruan Not sure if it may help. Might be you can share your jdbc pool configuration to us?

Comment: @Quincy I don't think it would help, the problem started with the default Wildfly pool configuration and then I've just increased the maximum connection number (from 20 to 250, so it takes longer to be exhausted and a can flush them manually to avoid an application crash). After additional tests, I've updated the question: what could cause a connection leak in the pool, when using JPA only?

Comment: @Heruan I observed there's broken pipe exception and it means the physical connection between wildfly and the DB is lost. Is there a firewall in between that would terminate the connection? To overcome this, the background-validation should better be switched on for the connection pool.

Comment: I'm not sure - you use that chained code, returning ".getResultList()" on calling "list()" - maybe the Query object can't be garbage collected!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out what it was: Java 8 parallel streams on lazy collections. Simply don't use parallel streams for collections of JPA relationships, since it may use multiple connection from the pool during stream processing but on collecting the results only one connection is returned to the pool while the others fails with an *attempt to return the same connection twice*, eventually exhausting the pool.